# Tensorflow backend: unable to use gpu

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the output of `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())`

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8087623604945614369
]
```

Here is the output of `pip list | grep tensorflow`:

```
tensorflow-gpu (1.4.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.4.0rc3)
```

I can confirm that I have installed cuda 8.0 and cudnn on my machine and the output of `nvidia-smi` shows the GPU along with other details. Can someone please help me to understand why the output from `print(device_lib.list_local_devices())` doesn't show the GPU?rr

---

Tried this simple tensorflow example:

```
 with tf.device('/gpu:0'):

 a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
 b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
 c = tf.matmul(a, b)

 sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
 print(sess.run(c))
```

Error:

```
Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]
```

Comment: What output do you get from running a Python shell and entering `import tensorflow as tf` and then `sess = tf.Session()`?  It's also possible that the output of the `nvidia-smi` command might be useful.

Comment: Do you have CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable set by any chance? Did you try the things mentioned in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2882?